# How to get the IP address of remote endpoint by knowing the mac address in PHP?

Tags: php, ip-address

I tried something like this which didn't work for me.

```
<?php 
$ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR") ;
Echo "Your IP is " . $ip;
?>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is your desired output?

Comment: `$ip=\`arp | grep '$MAC_ADDRESS' | cut -f1 -d' '\`;` - but you really don't understand what it is you're asking here.

Answer (score 1):

You can't resolve a MAC to an IP. MAC's are used on ARP-Layer and works only on local LAN.
A MAC is bound to a network adapter/device. On this device, you can assign multiple IP-addresses for IP-protocol stuff.

Are you talking about MAC's? 
They look like 00-50-56-C0-00-08 
Sometimes also separated with ":"

Update after the comment:
You can't resolve a MAC to an IP.
There are some tricks around that you can try.
If the current PC had contact to that device, the IP may store in the ARP-cache.
The other trick if you are using a DHCP server you can query this one if it assigned to IP to that MAC.

Comment: I have few IP based phones hows MAC address are separated with ":", I am writing a script in PHP to find the IP address of those devices using the mac address. or you can share the other to get the ip address of devices. thanks

Comment: I extended the answer. When the phone access your php programm they have an IP. i don't get the point where only the MAC is know. Do you want to access the webservers in the phone by php?

Comment: I can see the IPs of my phone manually but i am implementing a program to access phone from remote location.since my phone doesn't have a constant IP(phone IP keeps on changing) so thats way i want to get the IP from the MAC address since mac address are fixed, based on this trick i can get the IP which ever is assigned to it by the DHCP.

Comment: In this case you need to query the DHCP server. You can also bind an ip to a mac within the DHCP server. Then the IP will always bound to that phone. I think this is more easy. You say "remote location" - it is outside the lan? If yes, then you may have problem accessing the DHCP server.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
if($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] != ""){
  $IP = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
  $proxy = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
  $host = @gethostbyaddr($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]);
}else{
  $IP = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
  $proxy = "No proxy detected";
  $host = @gethostbyaddr($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
}
```

Comment: I tried this in PHP but didn't work.it didn't shown me any output.thanks